# How do I feed a monster drugged meat?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

When fighting Deviljho, I was tempted to feed him drugged meat to make it sleep for sharpening and sleep-bombing. After some research, I know a monster would eat a meat bait when it is hungry (and not fighting? not sure), indicated by the drooling symbol near the map's monster icon.

However, in most fights, when the monster is hungry with the drooling symbol, they run away almost instantly (e.g. Deviljho). When they are running away, even if the lv3 scout flies indicate their destination, it's unlikely a player can catch up, or get there fast enough to place down the meat (w/ or w/o fast travel). Then how do I feed a monster drugged meat?

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly because monsters are more wary of the surroundings in *World*, including even Deviljho. To drug the monster, it must be:

- exhausted (obviously),
- carnivore (do not expect that Diablos or Kirin to be drugged), and
- **not engaged**.

The third part-in which the subject must not be engaged-leads to a trouble because monsters will prioritize in shrugging you or other invading monsters off. However, since the monster will momentarily stop before actually fleeing, and even try to fight back moreso in *Iceborne*, you can use those moments to put the meat and then hide the offenders' trace and make it focus on the meat instead. To hide yourself, you could hide in a bush, use a Ghillie Mantle, a smoke bomb, or just run away. Fending off other monsters is much more difficult since there is a chance for the monster to flee before the dung pod even works.

Also, (Ebony) Odogaron has a special gimmick in which it eats meat to get frenzied even without being exhausted. Normally it reaches for the meat it always carries, but if there is a drugged meat, sometimes Odogaron will try that instead.

Personally, though, since you mentioned recuperating such as sharpening, if you have access to such hiding methods, I would rather just use them directly for this purpose. For sleep-bombing, your Palico, Sleep ammo/coating or sleep weaponry seem to be more realistic, and for poisoning, well, there is a poison smoke bomb.

Comment: There is also a claim that a walking (not flying ones such as Rathalos) starving monster can be interrupted with putting meat on the path, not only on its final destination. I didn't put it in the answer because I have yet to test it, but if I get to test it somehow, I will put it in the answer.

Comment: I find it hilarious that bush hiding is completely not mentioned. I guess so few people used it that they completely forgot it existed (crouch in tall grass/bush/etc). There are a lot of environment to hide in everywhere.